# Why does Rake crash my Mac OS X ?

Tags: ruby, macos, crash, rake

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.2 and I've got a strange problem with rake and my ruby applications.

Has soon as I launch a rake command my mac crashes and ask me to reboot (dark screen). This occur when I try to run a Rakefile or even simply if I type:

```
rake --version
```

I tried reinstalling rake by running the install.rb file of the latest version of rake package but the problem still remains. OS X Crash also occur when I try to install rubygame through the gem command.

I'm using gem 1.3.1 and here is my version of ruby :

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

Does any one already had this problem and solved it?

Comment: I'm running the same versions of ruby and gem and am not seeing the behavior you describe. Mine comes back with "rake, version 0.8.7". I'd ask you what version *you're* running, but ... :-)

Comment: It's completely weird, I installed rake-0.8.7 too.
I'll try to completely remove rake and install it again, maybe there is a corrupted file in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was corrupted and the install.rb script of the rake package did not replaced it on reinstall. After replacing the rake file manually it worked:

```
Vinz-2:bin vcogne$ whereis rake
/usr/bin/rake
Vinz-2:bin vcogne$ sudo cp ~/Desktop/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake /usr/bin/
```

I did the same for the location the "which rake" command gave me.